# Embedding of $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R^2})$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R^2})$ for all $2\leq p<\infty$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I need to prove the above embeddeding. Here as $p=n$ as we are working in $\mathbb{R^2}$ so we can't apply the sobolev embedding also the domain is not bounded.  Any idea regarding how to approach this would be beneficial.

Comment: That's a corollary of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality. A proof can be found in Brezis' "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations", Corollary 9.11.

Comment: Ok thanks . Let me check this